# Обработка нажатия клавиши на клавиатуре и на форме

Tags: c#

При написании некоего калькулятора необходимо организовать ввод как с кнопок, так и с клавиатуры. Обработка корректного ввода с клавиатуры была реализована при помощи `KeyPress`, который в параметры получает `(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)`, далее в зависимости от ситуации либо блокирует некорректное нажатие клавиши, либо пропускает правильное.
Для кнопок самым логичным выходом, на мой взгляд, являлось обращение к этому же `KeyPress`. Для чего кнопки были привязаны вот к такому обработчику:

```
private void num_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char tmp = ((Button)sender).Text[0];
    textBox1_KeyPress((Object)textBox1, new KeyPressEventArgs(tmp));
}
```

И далее происходит что-то непонятное. Чисто теоретически, `KeyPress` получает ровно то же самое на вход, что и при обращении к нему при вводе с клавиатуры. То есть должна происходить аналогичная обработка. Происходит следующее (следующее происходит согласно пошаговому проходу программы в отладчике):
программа благополучно заходит в `KeyPress`, проходит все проверки, все хорошо, все корректно, однако не печатает в текстбокс символы. Конечно, можно прикрутить некие костыли с принудительным вводом (что и было реализовано), но хочется понять что именно идет не так, и как это можно исправить в данной конкретной ситуации.

UPD:
Вопрос решен! Спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Вот этот ход отлично сработал:

```
char tmp = ((Button)sender).Text[0];
textBox1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send(tmp.ToString());
```

А мне, пожалуй, необходимо внимательнее вчитываться в теорию:)

Answer (score 2):

> Для кнопок самым логичным выходом, на мой взгляд, являлось обращение к этому же KeyPress.

В Windows у окон (не путать с контролами) есть очередь системных сообщений. Все движения мыши, нажатие кнопок и т.д. попадают в эту очередь. 
Дальше системные события преобразуются в объекты типа Message и передаются в контролы.
Все Message можно увидеть, если наследовать Control или его производные и переопределить виртуальный метод [WndProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(v=vs.110).aspx).
А как-раз в базовом методе Control.WndProc есть код, который на основе данных находящися в Message, вызывает, например, посылку события KeyPress и передает в него часть данных из Message.
К событию KeyPress вы можете подключить свой обработчик и как-то среагировать на событие. Т.е. вызов своего обработчика не влияет на системную очередь событий.

В системную очередь можно из своего кода послать системные события, и тем самым эмулировать движения мыши, нажатия клавиш. Но для этого надо использовать Win API функции [SendMessage](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage), [mouse_event](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mouse_event), [keybd_event](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.keybd_event).

В .NET есть метод SendKeys.Send, который проще использовать вместо keybd_event.

Answer (score 1):

Метод `textBox1_KeyPress` вызывается контролом (`TextBox`), когда контрол обрабатывает события нажатия кнопок клавиатуры. К моменту вызова Вашего метода (`textBox1_KeyPress`) контрол уже получил всю информацию о вводе с клавиатуры и (частично) ее обработал. Когда Вы в Вашем коде вызываете `textBox1_KeyPress`, контрол понятия не имеет о том, что Вы бы хотели, чтобы он почувствовал событие ввода с клавиатуры.

[SendKeys.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
char tmp = ((Button)sender).Text[0];
textBox1.Focus();
SendKeys.Send(tmp.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы обработчике события нажатия на кнопку вызываете обработчик события ввода с клавиатуры который не имеет никакой обратной связи с вашим полем ввода. т.е. когда фокус ввода на поле и нажата клавиша на клавиатуре, поле ввода (ваш контрол отслеживающий ввод) любезно уведомляет всех кто интересуется данным событием по списку в порядке живой очереди (подписчиков на событие может быть много) что данное событие произошло. Что там будет далее с этой информацией и будет ли тот же подписчик вызываться другими методами его мало интересует.

Чтобы было понятнее как работает подписка на события представьте себе работника почты который получая новый номер журнала доставляет его по адресам из списка подписчиков. Если вам этот же журнал доставит кто-то другой или же вы сами его купите почтальон об этом будет не в курсе и никаких действий в связи с этим не предпримет до тех пор пока вы его не уведомите.